# How does jQuery trigger events?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how jQuery's `.trigger('click')` method works.

I've searched the jQuery source code, but I can't find anywhere that `dispatchEvent` or `fireEvent` are used outside of tests and the sizzle source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/search?q=dispatchEvent&type=Code

How does query trigger browser events?

Comment: There is no need to search, [event.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/f9ad13c9ec8967916427642db2883a1bf3bccd86/src/event.js)

Comment: @BlackSheep where in that file does jQuery actually dispatch the event on the target?

Comment: Well, as you can see the file contains 859 lines and just like other modules of the source code it's very spaghetti-like , there is a `dispatch` function on line 351.

Comment: @BlackSheep which still does not contain any event dispatching code. I eventually figured out it was using an object called `specials` and executing the `.click()` function if available, otherwise falling back to executing `on click`